# Opening PayPal form in browser - jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am developing an App using `jquery mobile`. In the app i have `PayPal Donate button` which uses `inAppBrowser` to open the form. I tried to submit my application to the `iTunes Store` but i got the following rejection,

```
We found that your app includes the ability to collect charitable donations within the app, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines

While donations may not be taken within an application, it is possible to provide a donation link to your web site. This link should launch Safari to collect the donation.
```

I tried to add `rel="external"` to the form but it didn't work.

```
<form rel="external" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
```

How can i force the PayPal form to open in the browser but not in the App itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `target="_blank"` attribute to your form tag.  Your form would now look like this:

`<form rel="external" target="_blank" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">`

All **rel** does is allow some search engines to get more information about the page, I don't think it would have any effect.